# How to combine these two xml files

Tags: java

File employe = new File("E:five/emplo.xml");
            File stud = new File("E:/one/two/student.xml");
how to combine these two files in one file object

Comment: Hi visakh, welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried, and we can try to help.

Comment: You want to merge the content and reopen it?

Comment: Please provide two examples and desired output.

Comment: Do you want to merge the two XML documents (so that it's properly formed under a single root) and simple append one file to the other?

Comment: Down voted due to lack of information, resulting in inability for others to answer the question. I'll cancel if the question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge two standard text files then you can just use filewriters and filereaders.

I assuming that this is not some xml specific thing as I am not experienced with them.

Here is how to read a file (without the exception handling):

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); // the only reason I use this is because I am used to line by line handling
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
  // do something with each line
}
```

You could read each file into an arraylist of strings then output using:

```
FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(file, toAppend);
fout.write(msg);
fout.close();
```

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   File employe = new File("E:five/emplo.xml");
   File stud = new File("E:/one/two/student.xml");
  
   Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse(employe);
   Document doc2 = dBuilder.parse(stud);
   doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      doc2.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Comment: this is my code iam using dom parser,i want combine these two files in single files

Comment: Can you combine the files and then parse using DocumentBuilder?

Comment: If you can combine the files and then parse, then combine the files using a FileReader / FileWriter to a new file and then you can parse that one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] filenames = new String[]{ "emplo.xml", "student.xml"};
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("merged.xml");
for (String filename : filenames) {
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename);
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    inputStream.close();
}
outputStream.close();<br/>
```

or you can also use `SAXParser`

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   File employe = new File("E:five/emplo.xml");
   File stud = new File("E:/one/two/student.xml");
  
   Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse(employe);
   Document doc2 = dBuilder.parse(stud);
   doc1.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      doc2.getDocumentElement().normalize();

Comment: but ididnt add two files can u help me